# Regex (three chars then 3-7 digits) then optional one character

Tags: regex

I would like to match three characters followed by 3-7 digits, then optional a character or more, total string should between 6 and 20 characters.

I wrote the following, but it's not working

```
^([a-zA-Z]{3}[1-9]{3,7}([a-zA-Z])?){6,20}$
```

Thanks!

Comment: How is this going to reach 20 characters? 3 characters plus max 7 digits and an optional character will be at most 11?

Comment: the {6, 20} mean you want all of that 6 to 20 time, it doesn't report to the total string length, but to the number of time of the last bracket.

Comment: Does the part you want to match have to be at the beginning of the string?

Comment: The optional character means either one or more (up to a maximum of 20). so what I'm looking for something lile:
AAA111 or AAA111L or AAA111LASA .. 
and forgot to mention no spaces is allowed. and yes it has to match the whole string (from the start to the end of textbox value field)

Comment: if defining the string to be between 6 and 20 is hard. I can use jquery to validate this. then maybe I need to validate the string to be on the format of (three characters) + (3-7 digits), then optional any characters (lets say between 1-6), all without spaces

Answer (score 1):

If the total length of the string should be 6-20 characters you could use a positive [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to asserts that from the beginning of the string `^` until the end of the string `$` there are 6-20 characters `^(?=[a-zA-Z1-9]{6,20}$)`

Then match 3 characters `[a-zA-Z]{3}` and match 3-7 digits `[1-9]{3,7}`

**Note** that you use `[1-9]` which will not match a zero (which would be `[0-9]`)

After that you match  zero or more upper or lowercase characters `[a-zA-Z]*$` until the end of the string.

[`^(?=[a-zA-Z1-9]{6,20}$)[a-zA-Z]{3}[1-9]{3,7}[a-zA-Z]*$`](https://regex101.com/r/cLwbzV/1/)